# Duplicating rows conditionally in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to duplicate each observation based on the count. For example:

- If `count == 3`, duplicate the observation **three** times but replacing the **count with 1 each time**.
- If `count == 1`, no changes are required.

```
# Sample data
df <- tibble(
x = c("A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A"),
y = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y"),
count = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)

# Target output
df <- tibble(
x = c("A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"),
y = c("Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y"),
count = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

Comment: You missed the `c()` around your vectors in the data examples.

Comment: `tidyr::uncount(df, count) %>% mutate(count = 1)`

Comment: @thelatemail I'm getting old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`,

```
df %>% uncount(count, .remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(count = ifelse(count==3,1, count))
```

The output is

```
   x     y     count
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     Y         1
 2 C     N         1
 3 C     Y         1
 4 C     Y         1
 5 C     Y         1
 6 B     N         2
 7 B     N         2
 8 C     N         1
 9 A     N         1
10 A     Y         1
```